# limit search on custom column of pages library

Tags: search, search-results, search-scope, result-source

I am very new to search. I have been searching this but could not find any.
Here is my problem:

We have a custom column created for Pages Library **EdwSearchTag**. When ever we add file to pages library, we will add few keywords to EdwSearchTag column as tags.

Eg: When we add Denials.aspx to pages lib, We will add 90405;denials;Hospital; to EdwSearchTag column. Like this each page will have its own keywords.

When user search for 90405 it should result in denials.aspx alone.

So far I am using this to limit to pages library:

```
{searchTerms}  Path:{SiteCollection.URL} (contentclass:STS_ListItem_850)  FileExtension=aspx
```

But how to restrict my search to only look into EdwSearchTag column alone.

Please share your ideas/links.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to convert EdwSearchTag into a managed property. After that you can run searches by adding EdwSearchTag as a search term in your query (for e.g. EdwSearchTag contains denials, will return only search results for column values containing denials)

Here are the steps:

-Choose a field in a list or document library.

-Make sure some items in the list or library have the field and it is filled out.

-Run an incremental crawl to add the field into the index as a crawled property.

-Create a managed property. (Application Management > Manage Service Applications > Search Service Application > Search Schema)

-Run a full crawl.

-Wait patiently.

-Enjoy searching on your new managed property.

More details below:
https://johnrossjr.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/creating-custom-managed-properties/

Comment: Ok I will try that. So users have to search like this **"EdwSearchTag:denials"**?, is it not possible to get the result just by searching "denials"?

Comment: I would say explore the query settings in the Search Results web part a bit more. EdwSearchTag:denials is just one of the options using Manual value for a managed property. You can pass query terms from Search box, read url parameter, read query strings etc.